# Is second moment of exponential also Memory Less?

Tags: conditional-expectation

I know that the exponential is memory less and that means that:
$$ 
E[X\mid X>1]=1+E[X]
$$
Now, does the memory less property also hold for the second moment?
Specifically, is the following true? $$
E[X^2\mid X\geq1]=1+E[X^2]
$$

Comment: I don't see why someone downvoted my question ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it should say
$$
\operatorname{E}(X^2\mid X\ge 1) = \operatorname{E}((1+X)^2).
$$
The conditional distribution of $X-a$ given that $X\ge a$ is the same as the marginal (i.e. unconditional) distribution of $X$.  Hence the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $X\ge a$ is the same as the marginal distribution of $a+X$.

Comment: Nice, exactly what I was looking for.